# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, retrofit

Error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have two model class which are as follows .

MovieComments.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class MovieComments {


    @SerializedName("page")
    public int page;


    @SerializedName("results")
    public List<MovieComment> movieCommentList;


    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    public int totalPage;


    @SerializedName("total_results")
    public int totalResults;

}
```

And Another Model class  MovieComment.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MovieComment {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;


    @SerializedName("author")
    public String author;


    @SerializedName("content")
    public String content;
}
```

In IMovieService class the Retrofit Interface.

```
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Path;
import retrofit.http.Query;

public interface IMovieService {
    @GET("3/movie/{id}/reviews")
    Call<MovieComments> getComments(@Path("id") int id, @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
}
```

I get the data in MainActivity as:

```
 private void getCommentsFromWeb() {

        final MovieComments[] movieComments = new MovieComments[1];
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.MOVIE_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        IMovieService iMovieService = retrofit.create(IMovieService.class);

        Call<MovieComments> movieCommentsCall = iMovieService.getComments(movie.id, Constants.API_KEY);
        movieCommentsCall.enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<MovieComments>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<MovieComments> response) {
                movieComments[0] = response.body();
                Log.e(TAG, "data" + movieComments[0].page);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

In build.gradle

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
 compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
```

Comment: The error you're getting is build process error. Please post your `.gradle` files - java source shouldn't be source of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle probably has problems with resolving dependencies for your project, since you compile retrofit's gson converter via maven, but gson itself from `jar` file.

Swap `compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')` for `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` instead. Maven should be able to handle the dependencies correctly.

Edit: actually I think you can skip `gson` dependency entirely. `gson-converter` includes it as well